# Trying to find if numbers are odd/even/composite/prime

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes, composite

I have the following array of numbers :

```
var array = [5,9,12,19,23,24,31,44,49,62];
```

and I am trying to find out for each one if they are either even and composite, odd and composite, or odd and prime. I began by trying to find the numbers which are even and composite:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]%2 === 0 && array[i]%i === 0) {
        console.log(array[i]+" is even and composite")
    }
}
```

The problem is I only get 12 when I should get 12,24,44,62. It seems to stop at 12. What could be the issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: The comparison `array[i]%i === 0` is not checking whether `array[i]` is a composite number or not, but is instead checking whether `array[i]` is divisible by `i`. For the cases of 24, 44, and 62, they do not make your condition true because 24 is not divisible by 5, 44 is not divisible by 7, and 62 is not divisible by 8. You need to re-work your condition to check whether a number is composite or not.

Comment: Well, neither is 12 divisible by 5, but it still somehow shows it.

Comment: When you are evaluating 12, `i` has the value of 2, which 12 is divisible by. To clarify, your condition currently checks whether a number is even (divisible by 2) and is divisible by its index in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tackle each problem as a function to make it easier.

For example: to find the even numbers in the array

```
function isEven(n) {
   return (n % 2) === 0  //to get even numbers
}

function isOdd(n) {
   return (n % 2) === 1  //to get odd numbers
}
```

then write another function to check for the composite and prime numbers. Won't be fun if i do all the work for ya.

```
function isComposite(n) {
   //Enter check for composite numbers here
}

function isPrime(n) {
   //Enter check for prime numbers here
}
```

and then to get the even numbers in the array you could simply use the filter method for arrays passing your pre-written test functions as arguments, if you don't know what it is look it up. But basically it checks if each element in an array passes a test and then creates another function from it.

```
array.filter(isEven) // This would create a new array of all the even numbers in your array
```

You could also chain the function calls to find even and composite numbers.

```
array.filter(isEven).filter(isComposite)  //would give you all the even and composite numbers in your array
```